# Angular 2/4 - empty components (just view)

Tags: angular, angular-components

My question is:

*What do you guys think of empty (?) components in Angular? Is that a mistake to create ones? Or is that a normal thing?*

By empty I mean:

**Components that have only basic structure and HTML in it.**

Example:

**Component.ts**

```
    @Component({
        selector:...
        templateUrl: 'xxxx.html'
    })
    export class XXXXX {
    }
```

**.html**

```
    <p> Hi </p>
```

Comment: why would it be a mistake ?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Angular - and I'm not really sure if there are some better ways to do things like this that would not require creating a new component.

Comment: Depend what you want to use it for?
You want to show HTML?
Or want to make a Utill that does multiple things and return data?

Comment: Just to show something - but in this case, it's a component that all 404 statuses will redirect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components are the most basic building block of an UI in an Angular application. It's not required to put complex logic into your component. For example, it can be a simple wrapper for another component.

Example of a very simple component:

```
@Component({selector: 'greet', template: 'Hello {{name}}!'})
class Greet {
  name: string = 'World';
}
```

[More about components in Angular docs.](https://angular.io/api/core/Component)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do understand what components are just curious how to deal with certain things like this one. I was also hoping for some discussion about that but I guess that there will be no different answer than yours. I thought there were some different approaches. It's a wrong site for such a question I suppose or perhaps my question is wrong. Anyway thanks!

Comment: @Gorsky Your question is not wrong, every framework can have different approach, so asking is perfectly fine. In Angular, as I said in the answer, there is not limitation about components complexity. If my answer is helpful, it would be great if you mark it as accepted!